# PyQt QWizard validation and button override

Tags: python, qt, validation, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a multi-page QWizard where I need to do some validation of numeric input. Multiple QLineEdit widgets can contain any float type or the string 'None', where 'None' is the default null value for a REAL column in sqlite. QValidator can validate the float part but as it validates as you type it is not suitable for evaluating a 'None' string (eg user could enter NNNooo instead). Validation on loss of focus on each QLineEdit is not suitable either as the user may not select each QLE before moving to next page. All I can think of is to validate all fields by overriding/intercepting the next button call. In the QWizard page I can disconnect the next button (can't get new style disconnect to work):

```
self.disconnect(self.button(QWizard.NextButton), QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, QtCore.SLOT('next()'))
self.button(QWizard.NextButton).clicked.connect(self.validateOnNext)
```

Inside QWizardPages inside init I can connect to the next button (new style):

```
self.parent().button(QWizard.NextButton).clicked.connect(self.nextButtonClicked)
```

But disconnecting the QWizard's next slot doesn't work (2 ways):

```
self.parent().button(QWizard.NextButton).clicked.disconnect(self.next)
```

I get an AttributeError: 'MyWizardPage' object has no attribute 'next'

```
self.parent().disconnect(self.parent().button(QWizard.NextButton), QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, QtCore.SLOT('next()'))
```

I get no error but next button still works

The problem with each QWizardPage connecting to 'next' slot is that the init method in each of the pages is executed during wizard start-up - so when next is pressed all wizard pages nextButtonClicked() methods are executed. Perhaps I could disable all next functionality on QWizardPage onFocus(), implement its own next functionality, and do the same for each page, but seems overly complex

What was a simple validation problem is now a signal/slot interceptor issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create your own validator subclass that will accept custom values. All you need to do is reimplement its [validate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html#validate) method.

Here's a simple example that uses [QDoubleValidator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdoublevalidator.html):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Validator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator):
    def validate(self, value, pos):
        text = value.strip().title()
        for null in ('None', 'Null', 'Nothing'):
            if text == null:
                return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable, text, pos
            if null.startswith(text):
                return QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate, text, pos
        return super(Validator, self).validate(value, pos)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.setValidator(Validator(self.edit))
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```